Difference between the number of zeros of $f$ and $f'$ subjected to the constraint $|f(z)|=M$ on $C$
I am reading the book A Course on Modern Analysis Fifth edition section 6.4 (on page 120).
The theorem says that the number of zeros of $f(z)$ exceed the number of zeros of $f'(z)$ in the same region.
It's proof started with considering $f(z)=Me^{i\theta(z)}$ on $z\in C$. Obviously, in such case $\theta$ must be real.
And $$f'(z)=Me^{i\theta}i\theta' \quad , \quad f''(z)= Me^{i\theta}\left[i\theta''-\theta'^2\right]$$
now the number of zeros of $f$ - number of  zeros of $f'$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\, dz$$
$$=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{\frac{f(z)}{f'(z)}}\left(\frac{f(z)}{f'(z)}\right)' \, dz=-\frac{1}{2\pi  i} \oint_C \frac{\theta ''}{\theta '} \, dz$$
The book considered \textcolor{red}{$s$ to be the arc measured from a fixed point and $\psi$ to be the angle tangent to $C$ made with $0x$}.
Then
$$=-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \log(\theta')\Bigg|_{C}=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left[\log \frac{d\theta }{ds}-\log\frac{dz}{ds}\right]_C$$
It proceeds by saying that $\log\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ is purely real so it vanishes, and $\log\frac{dz}{ds} =i\psi$. Hence the number of zeros of $f$ - number of  zeros of $f'$ is $\frac{\psi}{2\pi}$.
(1) I don't understand the red part. What does it mean by 'the arc measured from a fixed point' and 'the angle tangent to $C$ made with $0x$'?
(2) Just in case I still don't understand the proof after the first question answered. Why is $\psi$ positive?
Any help is appreciated
